# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, laravel

why every time on submit an error occurs, I think it is correct

Controller :

```
public function create()
{
    $author1['tambah_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('username','id');
    $author1['id_author'] = \DB::table('authors')->lists('id');

    return View::make('article.add',$author1)->with('authors',$author1);
}
```

View :

```
{{ Form::select('author',
                array_merge(['' => 'Pilih Author'], $tambah_author),
                $id_author,
                array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

when submit it generates an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `articles` (`judul`, `body`, `author_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sadsadd, sadas, 2, 2016-07-01 12:44:54, 2016-07-01 12:44:54))
```

Comment: Is there an author with id 2? Where is the code for inserting into DB?

Comment: public function store()
 {
  $article = new Article();
  $article->judul = Input::get('judul');
  $article->body = Input::get('isi');
  $article->author_id = Input::get('author');
  $article->save();

  return Redirect::to('article');
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can put in a check to ensure there is a valid corresponding author.

```
public function store() { 
    $article = new Article(); 
    $article->judul = Input::get('judul'); 
    $article->body = Input::get('isi'); 
    $article->author_id = Author::find(Input::get('author'))->id;
    if (!$article->author_id) throw new Exception('not a valid author.');
    $article->save(); 
    return Redirect::to('article'); 
}
```

Comment: can not, error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: on `$article->author_id = Author::find(Input::get('author'))->id;` ?

Comment: its same, can not be

Comment: yes, on $article->author_id = Author::find(Input::get('author'))->id;